# issues with char recognition in pytesseract/tesseract-OCR. Recognize '+' as '4'

Tags: python, python-tesseract

As mentioned in the title, I'm having trouble recognizing char, the script recognizes '+' as '4'. how i can improve more the accury.
Example of the images below, along with the code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLDMr.jpg

I tried to optimize using the codes in #. But I was not successful

```
img = cv2.imread("imgbug.png")
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=1.98, fy=1.98, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
#img=cv2.threshold(cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (1, 1), 0), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
#img=cv2.threshold(cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 5, 75, 75), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cmd = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
xx = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img)
cv2.imshow('',img)
print(cmd)
print(xx)
```

```
My output is:
34+3=8
9+4=16
2+2=4

3 15 67 28 84 0
4 26 67 35 84 0
+ 29 67 44 82 0
3 45 67 58 84 0
= 59 71 73 80 0
8 75 67 88 84 0
9 16 39 28 56 0
+ 30 39 44 54 0
4 45 39 57 56 0
= 59 43 73 52 0
1 75 39 83 56 0
6 85 39 97 56 0
2 16 12 28 28 0
+ 30 12 44 26 0
2 45 12 58 28 0
= 59 15 73 24 0
4 75 12 87 28 0
```

Comment: Take a look at: [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html). All the OCR need preprocessing, in tesseract as a free option you need to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to greyscale, then set a threshold.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Something like this

This will increase the recognition rate, but I suspect that the problem is in the library itself. If this doesn't work, I recommend using a different library or maybe try something like google vision

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, it helped me a lot. However I still have the problem, but in other images, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: imgur.com/a/Pz5O4Mr - This image give me the same problem

Comment: Look. I've used pytesserect  and it SUCKS. Just use another machine learning based library. Searching on github will really help.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is applying `threshold` to the input image.

You have three input-images:

```py
img_lst = ["pfB7MnL.png", "0amEBuu.png", "6FHilyj.png"]
```

If you apply thresholding to each input image:

```py
for img_nm in img_lst:
    img = cv2.imread(img_nm)
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=3, fy=3, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
```

Results will be:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When you read:

```py
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
```

Result will be:

```
2+9=14
9+1=6
9+2=11

3+3=8
9+4=16
2+2=4

1+5=10
7+7=14
9+6=16
```

Code:

---

```py
import pytesseract
import cv2

img_lst = ["pfB7MnL.png", "0amEBuu.png", "6FHilyj.png"]

for img_nm in img_lst:
    img = cv2.imread(img_nm)
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=3, fy=3, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
    print(txt)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, it helped me a lot. However I still have the problem, but in other images, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Pz5O4Mr - This image give me the same problem

Comment: Maybe, or let me ask you, did you try the code with different params? Unfotunately there is no universal code for solving ocr problems. My suggestion is 1. Try threahold with different values, i.e. 0, 255 or 0, 128 2. If opt 1 is not working, try adaptive-threshold

Comment: I will try this way. however the images with the numbers are always random, it seems to me that when I modify the code I can solve some and fail to solve others.

Comment: i did some changes in thresold inputs, and seens to work for me. I will make some tests. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hope you will achieve success